# How to allow CKEditor within WebView to access the clipboard?

Tags: webview, ckeditor, javafx-2

I'm using a CKEditor 4.1.1 instance within my JavaFX apps' `WebView`. When i hit the paste-button of the editor, a window opens that tells me that the security settings of the browser prevent clipboard access.

As the browser in this case is the `WebView`component, how can i alter the according settings to enable clipboard access?

[image: security-settings]

Test App:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleWebView extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().load("http://ckeditor.com/demo");

    final Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

To reproduce:

1. Run the Test App, the ckeditor will display.
2. Type come text in an external editor such as notepad and copy the text.
3. Press the 3rd button to the right in the ckeditor toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is a general issue with javascript text editors running in a browser, not something WebView specific.

Default security settings for browser runtimes don't allow copy and paste via JavaScript.  As the pop-up shown in the screenshot in question shows, the user can still manually paste data into the editor via keyboard shortcuts, it's just that the paste button won't automatically paste data.

In Firefox and Chrome, I got exactly the same behaviour as WebView.  In IE, I got a prompt asking if I wanted to allow the web page to access the clipboard and was able to have the data pasted on clicking "Allow Access" to the prompt.

You could file a tweak request against the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) runtime project.  Note that the block is intentionally implemented as a security related feature, so such a feature request may be rejected.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Additionaly, I believe that in FF it is possible to grant JS an access to clipboard (although I don't remember if for all sistes from `about:config` or only for addons). Thus, such an option could be added to WebView too.

Comment: As an added note, I have been testing the TinyMCE editor in WebView and get the same behaviour. Copy/paste buttons don't work, Ctrl-C/Ctrl-P does.

Comment: I guess the question was: "Can we setup WebView that it can access Clipboard API in JS. And would not require any additional permission since this is supposed to be a Desktop Application."

Comment: @AsifAshraf I think the answer to your rephrased question is clear: "No".  Well at least as far as I know.  I haven't re-tested behavior lately, but it is unlikely to have changed unless somebody followed the recommendation of logging an issue in the JavaFX issue tracker, and the issue was then approved and implemented (which I doubt).

Comment: Perhaps you could find some ugly workaround, e.g. Overlay Java buttons for pasting, on top of the WebView, and use the [JavaFX clipboard API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html), then send the data to your editor via the [Java to JavaScript bridge API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/js-commands.htm#CIHJJIDA).